# How to insert symbols in a vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbols

I have a vector of 12 entities in Matlab.
a=[3 4 6 8 1 5 8  9  3 7 3 6 ]

I want to insert symbols at regular intervals along with the values. The final value of a looks like this.
a=[#3  4@  6&  8<  #1  5@  8&   9<   #3  7@  3&  6<]
As can be seen that the symbols are being repeated after 3 entities.
How can this be achieved in Matlab ?

Comment: So `a` is a string?

Comment: any variable that defines the patterns for symbols? Or you just want a specific solution to your question?

Comment: The symbols have been selected arbitrarily. However the pattern is repeated through out the length of vector.

Comment: As @Suever says, the output must be an array of `char` if you want it to contain symbols. If `a` is numeric, you can use `c = num2str(a)` to convert it, then add the symbols using whatever your rules are.

Comment: If I convert my numeric values into array of char using c = num2str(a) as explained by you, then how can I insert the symbols with the array at regular intervals?. The problem is that I want first element of array with #, second with @, third with & and fourth with <. The pattern is repeated periodically for next 5000 entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sprintf.
For example:

```
a=[3 4 6 8 1 5 8 9 3 7 3 6 ]
Z = sprintf('#%d %d@ %d& %d< ',a);
```

Produces

```
Z = #3 4@ 6& 8< #1 5@ 8& 9< #3 7@ 3& 6<
```

sprintf will repeat the string as many times as needed to use up a.

I couldn't tell where you wanted spaces, but if they are uniform, you can adjust the string pattern in the sprintf statement as needed

**Edit:** Added a space at the end of the sprintf statement in order to match OP's output string

Comment: That's simple and very good! If you add a space after `<` , it will be perfect. i.e. `Z = sprintf('#%d %d@ %d& %d< ',a)` gives the output expected by the OP i.e. `#3 4@ 6& 8< #1 5@ 8& 9< #3 7@ 3& 6< `

Comment: @Trogdor. Thanks your solution is very good. However can it be done that if  I have a binary (1 or 0) in vector a, there is no space between  the digit and symbol (like 1@), But if I have real number, then there is a blank space in between (like  4 &). Is it possible in Matlab?

Comment: Hm, that's a new question... in your first question you have the symbols leading the numbers, so I'm not sure the exact thing you're trying to solve, but here's one idea: you could retroactively remove extra spaces with something like this: `Z(find(Z=='1' | Z=='0')+1) = ''` This assumes that every character after a 1 or a 0 is a space, so if your situation doesn't allow that you'd have to add another qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

The key solution is to use `repmat` to replicate the symbols array to be the same length as the array of numbers.
The following example works when all elements of a are single digits:

```
S = ['#', '@', '&', '<']; %Symbols
a=[3 4 6 8 1 5 8 9 3 7 3 6 3 4 6 8 1 5 8 9 3 7 3 6];

A = char([3 4 6 8 1 5 8 9 3 7 3 6 3 4 6 8 1 5 8 9 3 7 3 6] + double('0')); %Convert digits to characters.
T = repmat(S, [1, ceil(length(A)/length(S))]); %Replicate S to be in length of A, or longer
T = T(1:length(A)); %Set T to same size as A
Z = char(zeros(1, length(A)*2));
Z(1:2:end) = T; %Fill symbols
Z(2:2:end) = A; %Fill numbers
```

Result:
`Z = #3@4&6<8#1@5&8<9#3@7&3<6#3@4&6<8#1@5&8<9#3@7&3<6`

---

**With spaces:**

```
S = ['#', '@', '&', '<']; %Symbols
a=[3 4 6 8 1 5 8 9 3 7 3 6 3 4 6 8 1 5 8 9 3 7 3 6];

A = char([3 4 6 8 1 5 8 9 3 7 3 6 3 4 6 8 1 5 8 9 3 7 3 6] + double('0')); %Convert digits to characters.
%T = repmat(S, [1, ceil(length(A)/length(S))]); %Replicate S to be in length of A, or longer
%T = T(1:length(A)); %Set T to same size as A
Z = char(zeros(1, length(A)*3)); %Allocate 3 times length of A (for symbol, for digit, and for space).

%#3 4@ 6& 8< #1 5@ 8& 9< #3 
Z(1:12:end)  = S(1);       %#
Z(2:12:end)  = A(1:4:end); %3
Z(3:12:end)  = ' ';        %' ' 
Z(4:12:end)  = A(2:4:end); %4
Z(5:12:end)  = S(2);       %@
Z(6:12:end)  = ' ';        %' '
Z(7:12:end)  = A(3:4:end); %6
Z(8:12:end)  = S(3);       %&
Z(9:12:end)  = ' ';        %' '
Z(10:12:end) = A(4:4:end); %8
Z(11:12:end) = S(4);       %<
Z(12:12:end) = ' ';        %' '
```

Result:
`Z =`
`#3 4@ 6& 8< #1 5@ 8& 9< #3 7@ 3& 6< #3 4@ 6& 8< #1 5@ 8& 9< #3 7@ 3& 6<`

Comment: actually after inserting the symbols, I want spaces between the entities like #3  4@  6&  8<   #1  5@  8&  9<  #3  7@  3&  6< . Can't this be done with the help of Matlab?

Comment: @Habib.Khan OK, With spaces... Can you tell us the purpose?

Comment: The symbols are compiler directives for performing specific action upon witnessing the symbol.

Comment: How can the process be done if I have mixed numeric values in single and  double digits as well?

Answer (score 0):

example array, `a=[3 4 6]`

insert '', number change to char.

`a=['3' '4' '6']` than

`a=['3' '^' '4' '#' '6']` or

`a=['3'; '^'; '4'; '#'; '6']`

it is impossible 3,4,6 as a number.

one array have one variable type. (as I know)